# Using Regex In Python To Find Substring?

Tags: python, regex

I have A string:

```
line_to_test = "http://website/[SequenceOfLetters&NumbersONLY].html"
```

I want a regex for matching the  above pattern:

what i have tried currently is:

```
c = len(re.findall(r"http:\/\/website\/([a-zA-Z0-9]?).html",line_to_test))
```

But `c` here comes to be null even when the `line_to_test` contains the pattern.

Comment: And what string did you tested with ?

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9]?)` = 1 or 0 letter or number - if you want a sequence, you want to replace `?` with `+`...

Comment: `test_string = "sdfmknldksjfnkmsd f,nm http://abc.de/msndkjnaskl.html"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` will only match 0 or 1 character. Try

```
c = len(re.findall(r"http:\/\/website\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html",line_to_test))
```

You can use an online service like regexr to test your regexes: http://regexr.com/3d301

Answer (score 2):

`?` means whatever preceded it was optional, in this case `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. That means you can have a letter or number either `0` or `1` times.

You should use the `*`, to select it `0` times or more, or use the `+`, to select it `1` times` or more.

Try this RegEx:

```
c = len(re.findall(r"http:\/\/website\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html",line_to_test))
```

If you used a `*`, it would be the same as `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?`, meaning `http://website/.html` would work.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d304)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks For the precise explaination !!